# What's the difference between FMS and FMC?

Tags: terminology, avionics, fms

What's the difference between FMS (Flight management System), and FMC (Flight management computer)?

Can the flight management computer be thought of as what's manipulating the input information from the performance/navigation databases, and the FMS as being what actually provides the information?

I understand the information that's involved with the system, I'm just trying to define the difference based off an analogy of sorts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### [SKYbrary](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Flight_Management_System)

Its definition is that the FMC is part of the FMS:

> An **FMS** comprises four main components:
>
> - The Flight Management Computer (**FMC**)
> - The Automatic Flight Control or Automatic Flight Guidance System (AFCS or AFGS)
> - The Aircraft Navigation System
> - An Electronic Flight Instrument System (EFIS) or equivalent electromechanical instrumentation.
>
> The FMC is a computer system that uses a large data base to allow routes to be pre-programmed and fed into the system by means of a data loader [...]

Putting that as a diagram plus the typical inputs and outputs:

> [image: diagram 1]
> — Own work

### [NASA](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19830060494)

Since the inception of the FMS, it's been the same:

> [image: diagram 2]
> — CREEDON, J. "Flight management systems-What are they and why are they being developed?." *Guidance and Control Conference.* 1973.

Comment: Typically, the CDU's (or MCDU's) are considered part of the FMS as well.

Comment: @ymb1
I know this was a long long time ago but I need the info from the second picture (the NASA one) for a scientific work. Do you have any access to the conference paper that includes this picture? I tried finding the whole document (in PDF form) on the internet but couldn't... I just need the page that the picture is on.
It would really mean a lot to me if you could help me with that matter.
Kind regards,
Niels

Comment: Hi @MyTree: The NASA download seems unavailable, but since that "paper is declared a work of the U.S. Government and therefore is in the public domain" (says so on the paper), you can try Sci-Hub or similar if you can access them, if not, there is a paywalled version that is easy to google for. If you want *just* that page, then [here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QX0T.png).